# ¿Puedo usar una misma id en varias etiquetas?

Tags: html, css

Quiero usar una misma id en unas etiquetas que se repetirán muchas veces en la página, esto para editar el codigo sin tener que escribir tantas lineas css.

**quiero saber si me dará errores o es mejor escribir css en las etiquetas html.**

```
caja que se repetirá <div id='caja'>--contenido--</div><style>#caja{background="#ff0000;"}</style>
```

**o si dará errores programando así**

```
<a style="background: #ff0000; color: #fff; padding: 10px;">hola</a>
```

Comment: los id en las etiquetas HTML deben ser únicos, si necesitas el mismo identificador en múltiples de ellas entonces usa una class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La [especificación](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute) es muy clara y contundente con respecto al `id`:

> ... the `id` attribute value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the
>   element's tree

---

> el valor del atributo `id` debe ser único entre todos los ID en el
>   árbol de elementos

Aunque no haya errores visibles en el documento, sí los hay a nivel de validación o de funcionamiento del código. Podemos hablar de *errores implícitos* en ese sentido.

Por lo tanto:

- no te recomiendo usar ids repetidos. Imagina un mundo donde se le otorgue el mismo número de carnet de identidad a varias personas, misma matrícula a los vehículos, el mismo número de teléfono a varias personas, el mismo número de cuenta bancaria ...
- no te recomendaría poner código de estilo directamente a los elementos, como aquí por ejemplo: `<a style="background: #ff0000; color: #fff; padding: 10px;">hola</a>` Es una **pésima práctica**. ¿Por qué? Por muchos motivos. Imagina una aplicación con cientos o miles de páginas con estilos aplicados directamente en los elementos. Y de repente al dueño de la página o aplicación se le antoja cambiar los colores, poner unos más acordes a la temporada de otoño o de verano. Ya te veo indagando entre los cientos o  miles de página para cambiar por el nuevo color. Como han comentado algunos, es mucho mejor usar clases y aplicar los estilos en las clases. Así, si hay que cambiar algo, lo cambias en un solo sitio, no en mil sitios.

#### Ejemplo de mala práctica

Supongamos que tienes esto y un buen día el jefe te dice que los fondos se ven más bonitos en azul... OMG ¿cómo piensas hacer ahora para cambiar, tú que habías pensado que el rojo era eterno?

```html
<p>En la página o archivo 1 de tu aplicación:</p>
<a style="background: #ff0000; color: #fff; padding: 10px;">hola</a>
<p>En la página o archivo 506 de tu aplicación:</p>
<a style="background: #ff0000; color: #fff; padding: 10px;">hola</a>
<p>En la página o archivo 99999 de tu aplicación:</p>
<a style="background: #ff0000; color: #fff; padding: 10px;">hola</a>
```

---

#### Ejemplo de buena práctica

Supongamos que tienes esto y un buen día el jefe te dice que los fondos se ven más bonitos en azul y que quiere la letra más grande... Y que recibirás un jugoso incentivo si lo haces antes del mediodía :)

```css
.by-temps {
  background: #ff0000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p>En la página o archivo 1 de tu aplicación:</p>
<a class="by-temps">hola</a>
<p>En la página o archivo 506 de tu aplicación:</p>
<a class="by-temps">hola</a>
<p>En la página o archivo 99999 de tu aplicación:</p>
<a class="by-temps">hola</a>
```

Vamos a por el incentivo, ¡son las 11:58!

```css
.by-temps {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p>En la página o archivo 1 de tu aplicación:</p>
<a class="by-temps">hola</a>
<p>En la página o archivo 506 de tu aplicación:</p>
<a class="by-temps">hola</a>
<p>En la página o archivo 99999 de tu aplicación:</p>
<a class="by-temps">hola</a>
```

---

### CONCLUSIÓN

- `id` único **siempre**
- agrupar por `class` cuando se requiera
- aplicar estilos aparte **siempre**

Answer (score 3):

La idea es que `id` sea único a nivel de la página, si múltiples elementos comparten `id` el HTML no es válido según especificación.  Por otro lado los navegadores normalmente son bastante tolerantes ante los errores en el HTML e ignoran los `id` repetidos.

Si lo quieres hacer para compartir el CSS entonces la manera correcta es asignar un mismo `class` a los elementos:

```
<div class="caja">...</div>
<div class="caja">...</div>
<div class="caja">...</div>
```

Y en el CSS:

```
.caja {
    ....
}
```

Fíjate que cambió `#` por `.`, con esto seleccionas por `class` en vez de `id`

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta es **SI**, si puedes, ya que los css buscaran todas las etiquetas con el mismo `id` para aplicar los css, aunque esta opción **no es nada recomendable**, es una mala idea y una mala practica, ademas de que tendrás varios problemas al utilizar dichas id en `javascript`.

Si requieres  alterar varias etiquetas a la vez debes de utilizar la propiedad `class`, que es mas común y de buena practica, ademas de que te ahora mucho trabajo cuando trabajes con javascript.

*Te dejo un ejemplo para que puedas ver la funcionalidad de ambas propiedades.*

```js
$("#cambcolorid").click(function(){
$("#unico").css({"color":'#1B5E20'});
});
$("#cambcolorclass").click(function(){
$(".repetido").css({"color":'#BF360C'});
});
```

```css
.repetido{
   font-size:25px;
   color:#abcdef;
}
#unico{
   font-size:35px;
   color:#EEFF41;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="unico"> esto es un texto con id unico</div>

<div class="repetido">
 este texto pertence a una clase
</div>
<div id="unico"> esto es un texto con id unico</div>
<div class="repetido">
 este texto pertence a una clase
</div>
<div id="unico"> esto es un texto con id unico</div>
<div class="repetido">
 este texto pertence a una clase
</div>

<button type="button" id="cambcolorid">cambiar color ID</button>

<button type="button" id="cambcolorclass">cambiar color class</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Puedo usar una misma `id` en varias etiquetas?

**Sí, pero no es recomendable** debido a la confusión que puede haber al trabajar con CSS o JS y tratar de coger el elemento por `id`, si crees que vas a necesitar 2 o más `id` entonces deberías de buscar otro selector válido como por ejemplo el recomendado `class` qué en CSS y JS se encuentra como `.` en vez de `#` como el `id`.