# Deshabilitar boton de un listado de consulta php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Tengo una tabla en la que el body se llena de una consulta php, en la ultima columna hay un boton el cual se repite en cada columna (por lo tanto el id en todos es el mismo), lo que quiero lograr es que cuando llene un input mediante un modal el boton se deshabilite pero solo el de esa columna, (si existe texto dentro del input entonces deshabilita el boton) mi codigo es este, conforme ponga codigo les explico...

Una ves que se enlista la consulta con este codigo, si el input esta vacio entonces le doy al boton (sign) jala los datos por el (id) de toda la fila y mediante un modal se ingresan los datos de mi session y hasta ahi todo bien si funciona, se registra en la tabla, pero lo que quiero es que despues de registrarse ese mismo boton se deshabilite para que solo se pueda hacer una vez..

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($execute)){

echo "<tr>
<td style='display:none;'>" . $row['id'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['fecha1'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['nombre1'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['defecto1'] . "</td>
<td><input id='atv{".$row['id']."}' type='text' onchange='mensajeChange()' value='" . $row['reportesistema1'] . "'>
</td>
<td>
<a href='#' onclick=modal_firmar_rmd('".$row["id"]."')><button disabled id='btn-firma_autorizar' onclick='return mensajeChange();' name='dtv{".$row['id']."}' type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModalCenter'>
Sign
</button></a>
</td>
```

";
}

En el Javascript no puedo poner el id del input y del boton porque al repetirse en la consulta de la tabla entonces si me lo deshabilita pero siempre toma el primer boton de la consulta y los demas los deja deshabilitados asi que trate de hacerlo de esta manera....

```
<script>
    
    function mensajeChange() {
      console.log("change");
      var mensaje = document.getElementById("atv"+id);
      var boton = document.getElementsByName("dtv"+id);
      console.log(boton)
      
      if (mensaje.value.trim() !== "") {
        boton.setAttribute('disabled', "true")
      } else {
        boton.removeAttribute('disabled');
      }
    }

    
  </script>
```

En el php en el input y el boton id='atv{".$row['id']."'} eso tambien funciona bien y dentro si me pone el correcto id de la fila que selecciono pero de ahi en mas ya no se que hacer....

Al haber texto dentro del input aun me muestra deshabilitado el boton..
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando le quito el texto aun me marca deshabilitado..
Soy nuevo en esto no se mucho si podrian ayudarme se los agradeceria.

Comment: Los id's deben ser únicos, siempre. Punto. No hay alternativa para esto, si los id's se repiten, el HTML es inválido. Puedes mejorar tu código para que el ID de cada botón sea diferente. Además me parece que confundes fila con columna.

Comment: Lectura recomendada: la respuesta a esta pregunta: [¿Puedo usar una misma ID en varias etiquetas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/213859/21)

Comment: Hola Rubens, lo que te comenta @jachguate es correcto. La solución es mucho más simple de lo que te imaginas, por ejemplo, podes agregar `$row["id"]` al `id` del `<button` y listo! PD: también deberías enviar el `$row['id']` al llamar al función en el `onclick`.